# OData $expand with different DB context

Tags: odata, webapi, ef-core-3.0

I have requirement like I need to expand the table of different database.

For example we have two model product and department. Both are in different database.

product table is in database1 and department table is in database2.

How can I expand database2..department under database1..product with odata $expand.

I am using C#,.netcore and EFCore. Please help me how can I do it with odata?

Comment: Hi did you manage to make progress with this?